# output an associative array, from SQL Select with PHP

Tags: php, sql, associative-array

I think my mind is just drawing a blank, but basically, I want to create an associative array from various sql results

The array needs to look like:

```
$people = array(
     "+1123456789" => "Phil"
);
```

Here is my SQL Statement

```
$sql = " SELECT phonenumber6, firstName FROM members WHERE departmentID = 4 AND phonenumber6 <> '+1';";
```

Thanks!

Edit: 
Also, there can be multiple rows that were selected by the sql statement

```
$sql = " SELECT phonenumber6, firstName FROM members WHERE departmentID = 4 AND phonenumber6 <> '+1';";

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  echo $people[$row['phonenumber6']] = $row['firstName'];
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $people[$row['phonenumber6']] = $row['firstName'];
}
```

### Addendum

Dunno what you want to echo. Anyway the right syntax is:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $people[$row['phonenumber6']] = $row['firstName'];
  echo $row['phonenumber6']. '=> '.$row['firstName']."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: you need to set an avatar, the world needs to know what lightning incarnate looks like L-/

Comment: @AJ: I will explain you why I am doing this (if you want). (in pvt of course)... lol anyway :)

Comment: Cool thanks... is there any way to make sure I'm doing it right to echo it out? This is what I tried (See edit above)

Comment: Because it wasn't working... but it was because of another issue I had... not that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an associated array from a mysql result set:

```
$assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc ($res);
```